# Naturality of $\varphi : \textbf{Vct}_K(V(x), w) \xrightarrow{\sim} \textbf{Set}(x, U(w))$ in the variable $x$ (Cats for the Working Mathematician).

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, natural-transformations, forgetful-functors

Consider the forgetful functor $U : \textbf{Vct}_K \to \textbf{Set}$ and the functor $V : \textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Vct}_K$ that takes an object $x$ in set to the $K$-vector space $V(x)$ with basis $x$ (a type of formal generation) and takes a map $h : x \to x'$ to the $K$-linear map $V(h)(\sum r_i x_i) \ (r_i \in K, x_i \in X) = \sum r_i h(x_i)$.

If $g: x \to U(w)$ is a map of sets, then:

> Each function $g: x \to U(w)$ extends to a unique linear transformation $f: V(x) \to w$, given explicitly by $f(\sum r_i x_i) = \sum r_i g(x_i)$.  The inverse of $\psi : g \mapsto (f = V(g))$ is $\varphi : f \mapsto f \vert_x$ the restriction of $f$ to the basis set $x$.  Thus we have components:

$$
\varphi_{x, w} : \textbf{Vct}_K(V(x), w) \xrightarrow{\sim} \textbf{Set}(x, U(w))
$$

(here $\varphi_{x,w} = \varphi$ from preceeding remark) of a family of bijections between such homsets.  These bijections happen to be natural in $x$ and $w$ so we have an isomorphism of bifunctors.

I'm trying to prove naturality of $\varphi$ in the first argument $x$ by showing that the following diagram is commutative for any general $h : x' \to x$ in $\textbf{Set}$ (yes, $x' \to x$ is the correct direction because $x$ is covariantly present in the *first* (thus, *domain-reversing*) argument of $\textbf{Vct}_K(V(\cdot), \cdot)$):

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\textbf{Vct}_K(V(x), w) @>{\varphi_{x,w}}>> \textbf{Set}(x, U(w))\\
@V{(Vh)^*}VV @VV{h^*}V \\
\textbf{Vct}_K(V(x'), w) @>{\varphi_{x',w}}>> \textbf{Set}(x', U(w))
\end{CD}
$$

where $h^*(g) \equiv g \circ h$, $(Vh)^*(g') = g' \circ (Vh)$, and I'm doing this by directly substituting in and expanding the above formulas.

---

We want to show that:

$$
h^* \circ \varphi_{x,w} = \varphi_{x', w} \circ (Vh)^*
$$

or equivalently that for any $g:V(x) \to w$ element in the upper left corner of the diagram we have:

$$
[h^* \circ \varphi_{x,w}(g)](y) = [\varphi_{x', w} \circ (Vh)^*(g)](y)
$$

for every $y \in V(x)$.  Using the definition of $h^*$ etc we have that the above is equivalent showing:

$$
[\varphi_{x,y}(g) \circ h](y) = [\varphi_{x', w} \circ g \circ (Vh)](y)
$$

for every $y \in V(x)$.  This is where confusion sets in for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close; to show this you don't need to refer to explicit elements $y \in V(x')$. To finish this, you need to take take advantage of the universal properties, and interpret what $\varphi_{x,w}$ really does to the morphisms.

To fill in those details you can create a commutative diagram like this:
[image]
This diagram might help. Here the $i$'s are inclusion morphisms.
The last equation you wrote corresponds to the commutativity of the colored-in diagram; see if you can reproduce this diagram by writing explicitly what $\varphi_{x,w}$ does.

Comment: How on Earth did you draw that beautiful diagram so quickly?

Comment: "Universal properties" of what in particular?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify that; $i: x \to U(V(x))$ is "universal" in the sense that for any $f: x \to U(W)$ with $W$ a vector space, we have that a unique $g: V(x) \to W$ with the diagram commuting. Here, $\phi$ is a function the other way around: we take a $g: V(x) \to W$ to its unique $\phi_{x, w}(g): x \to U(W)$ such that $U(g) \circ i = \phi_{x, w}(g)$. You might already understand all this so sorry if that's overkill. Anyways, that's what I meant, so apologies if that was confusing.

Comment: Also, I used PGF/TikZ. The manual has a lot of cool stuff to easily make such diagrams!

Comment: I don't understand all of what you said, so feel free to go more in depth in your post.  I understand about 65% of it.  What "made you" look at universality of $i : x \to U(V(x))$ for example.

Comment: Could you post the Tikz code for your rendering, so I can just copy / paste and start editing?

Comment: So to figure this out, I knew that we needed to figure out what exactly $\phi$ "does." But since I knew $i: x \to U(V(x))$ is universal, I deduced that $\phi$ must send each $g: V(x) \to W$ to the unique $f: x \to U(W)$ such that $U(g) \circ i = f$ (which exist by universality).  Thus $\phi$ is defined to go back and forth between $g: V(x) \to W$ and $f: x \to U(W)$ s.t. $U(g) \circ i = f$, which are in unique correspondence by universality.

Comment: And I don't think the code fits in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111423/discussion-between-trujello-and-abstractalgebralearner).

Comment: How did youknow that $i: x \to U(V(x))$ is universal?